# Mouse problem in org-mode export window

Tags: org-mode, mouse

When in `org-mode`, running the `export` command will open a windows with all the export options. However, my mouse scroll behaves erratically and I am not able to scroll down or move at all, not even by clicking on the scroll bars. (The problem is recurrent in both Linux and OS X, using `org-mode` version 8.2.10-30-gca21b7-elp, and GNU Emacs 24.4.1.)

See screen capture here:

[image: animated screencast]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using the same mouse or track pad in OSX & Linux?

Comment: For future visitors you should state which version of `org-mode` you are using.

Comment: @NVaughan -  Without moving your mouse, what happens if you use `SPC`, `DEL`, `C-n`, and `C-p`?

Comment: @Melioratus - Those keys work fine. It's only with the mouse that I get the problem.

Comment: @Melioratus - I am using different mice and trackpads in those systems.

Comment: Recursively bisect your init file to determine the minimum code needed to reproduce the problem. You can use command `comment-region` to comment a region of code (use `C-u` with it to uncomment) - comment out 1//2, then 3/4, 7/8,... until you have narrowed the problem down to the culprit code. Report here with more details when you have identified the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @NVaughan - Your mode line says `(Org ,)`. What is the minor mode you're using with org-mode?

Comment: @Melioratus - `C-h m` gives me: Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Cua Delete-Selection Desktop-Save Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow
Flx-Ido Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock Global-Pretty Global-Subword
Global-Undo-Tree Global-Visual-Line Ido-Ubiquitous Line-Number
Mac-Mouse-Wheel Menu-Bar Override-Global Recentf Savehist
Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Show-Smartparens Show-Smartparens-Global
Smartparens Smartparens-Global Subword Tex-Pdf Transient-Mark
Visual-Line Volatile-Highlights

Comment: @NVaughan - What happens if you **don't** use `C-c C-e` and call `M-x org-export-dispatch` directly?

Comment: @Melioratus - Pretty much the same.

Comment: @Melioratus It's not about the minor modes or configuration, I think it is the problem of Emacs itself. Even if you're using `emacs -q` to do the actions(or resize the window using keyboard/mouse/touchpad), the message will still be shown in minibuffer, I don't understand why the poster INSIST ON using Mouse to scroll the window for full content even though you got better solutions.

Comment: @CodyChan - I am not stubbornly insisting on using mouse. I can and in fact do use the keyboard. But I would also like to use once in a while the mouse, and would like to fix this problem---for it *is* a problem, me thinks.

Comment: @CodyChan - Thanks for the update! I **just replicated the issue** on my own machine. For other troubleshooters, to replicate, **keep resizing window smaller until effect appears**. The problem disappears with larger window sizes.

Comment: See also [Bug#19718 - read_filtered_event echos mouse events until character is inputted](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19718)

Answer (score 2):

When reading a export command org enters a modal state, where it
basically takes over Emacs reading of input. It does this by
continuesly reading an event and branching into it's corresponding
sub-menu until a full export-command is determined.

The function it uses for this purpose is `read-char-exclusive`, which,
as the name suggests, only reads characters and ignores any other
events (like e.g. mouse events).  These events are simply dropped,
though they are still echoed in the mini-buffer (for some reason).

Comment: Indeed. `read-char-exclusive` is related to `read-char` because they both call `read-filtered-event`. Try scrolling the mouse wheel after doing `M-: (read-char)`, `read-filtered-event` will throw an error. `read-char-exclusive` doesn't tell `read-filtered-event` to throw an error, it tells it to keep reading until it gets a valid input. Perhaps `read-filtered-event` should blank out the minibuffer if it gets a non-ascii character and `error_nonascii` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution**:

If you notice the top of the export-key-hint window, you'll get the line of  **"Use SPC, DEL, C-n, or C-p to navigate."**, so you can just use them to scroll up/down the window for hidden content.

**Simple solution about splitting window**:

```
(setq split-height-threshold nil)
(setq split-width-threshold 0)
```

When this happens, maximize the window(using Alt-F10 or other shortcut), and `C-c C-e`, it will open the key-options window side-by-side(horizontally), you'll see all the content of the window.

---

**Or if you want to split the window side-by-side or up-down according to your screen**, put this snippet into your `.emacs` or `init.el`:

```
;; Automatically split window horizontally(side-by-side) if current window is wide enough
(defun display-new-buffer (buffer force-other-window)
  "If BUFFER is visible, select it.

If it's not visible and there's only one window, split the current window
and select BUFFER in the new window.

If the current window (before the split) is more than 100 columns wide,
split horizontally(left/right), else split vertically(up/down).

If the current buffer contains more than one window, select BUFFER in the
least recently used window.

This function returns the window which holds BUFFER. FORCE-OTHER-WINDOW is ignored."
  (or (get-buffer-window buffer)
      (if (one-window-p)
          (let ((new-win
                 (if (> (window-width) 100)
                     (split-window-horizontally)
                   (split-window-vertically))))
            (set-window-buffer new-win buffer)
            new-win)
        (let ((new-win (get-lru-window)))
          (set-window-buffer new-win buffer)
          new-win))))
;; use display-buffer-alist instead of display-buffer-function if the following fails
(setq display-buffer-function 'display-new-buffer)
```

When this happens, maximize the window(using Alt-F10 or other shortcut), and `C-c C-e`, it will open the key-options window side-by-side(horizontally), you'll see all the content of the window. Adjust the `100` value in the snippet for your screen.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. It helps me with the auto-splitting of the windows, but not with the annoying display of (useless) mouse information in the minibuffer.

Comment: @NVaughan Your problem is you cannot see the whole content of the key-hint window so you scroll the window with your mouse then you see messages in the minibuffer. Not the problem that you scroll the window with your mouse then you see the messages in the minibuffer. I'm solving your original problem. And you got keep in mind that Emacs doesn't support mouse/touchpad as well as modern software.

Comment: @NVaughan And it seems that you cannot resize THAT window using keyboard/mouse/touchpad, if you try any tool to resize it, messages will be shown in the minibuffer. So as far as I know the only way to work it around is using a big screen or using my solution.

Comment: @ CodyChan. First of all, thanks for your help and comments. However, none of your methods allow me to solve the main problem, which---as you point---is for me to see the remaining export options of the window.

Comment: @NVaughan Using my methods, I never worry about the other window(such as key-hint window in magit, org-mode etc.) too small that I cannot see the full content of the window. Side-by-side-windows is the best solution to your problem.